# SSH still works without public key

Tags: ssh

There are two machines a and b. Add a's public key to b's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` then a can directly `ssh` to b.

However, when I remove the `.pub` file from a, it can still ssh to b without typing password but it takes longer time.

Why could this happen? I assume b uses a's private key to do some calculations to match all its authorized keys one by one. Is this correct? If so, could anyone give more details?

Comment: The .pub key file is not needed for the connection and you can have multiple public keys in `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Pub key and private key are generated together, so why pub key is not needed...

Answer (score 4):

Every private-key file always includes information about the corresponding public key.

The reason for the two files is that in OpenSSH, the passphrase encrypts the *whole* key file, including public parameters, so if you have multiple keys the client couldn't know which one is right unless it asked you for passphrases for all of them.

However, if the .pub files exist, the client can try sending them to server and find one that works *before* it has to ask for the unlock passphrase.

(For comparison, PuTTY's .ppk keys intentionally only encrypt the private parameters but not the public ones.)